# objective-c xml writer library with block syntax

Tags: objective-c, xml, xmlwriter

I'm looking for an XML **writing** library (not parsing) in objective-c with a block syntax.
For example in Ruby I use the nokogiri gem which allows me to construct XML in the following way:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|
  xml.MyRequest('xmlns' => 'blabla') {
    xml.ErrorLanguage 'en_US'
    xml.DetailLevel 'ReturnAll'
    xml.AllFeaturesForCategory 'true'
    xml.ViewAllNodes 'true'
    xml.CategoryID category_id
    xml.RequesterCredentials {
      xml.token 'dsfdsf'
    }
 }
```

I'm looking for its equivalent in objective-c.
Anybody knows of such library?

Answer (score 0):

Found this library https://github.com/monkeydom/TCMXMLWriter, it has a really nice API, for example:

```
[writer tag:@"Placemark" contentBlock:^{
  [writer tag:@"name" contentText:@"NYC"];
}];
```

Unfortunately it doesn't have a cocoapod yet, but it only requires importing two files into the project (TCMXMLWriter.h/m)